# How do I subset the last week for every month of a zoo object in R?

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have a few years of daily price data as a zoo object. What's the best way to subset the last week of 'every' month in R?

Here's how you can replicate it:

```
set.seed(123)
price <- rnorm(365)
data <- cbind(seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 365), price)
zoodata <- zoo(data[,2], as.Date(data[,1]))
```

I tried this option but it only returns the last week of the entire data set.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(zoodata, "months"), last, "1 week"))
```

Resulting output is:

```
2013-12-30 2013-12-31 
 1.0246732  0.8176594
```

I'm hoping to get the last week of every month so there should be at least 12 weeks of data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a minimal reproducible example of your problem. You should also show what you have tried so far and where you were unsuccessful.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I added code to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using the xts package

```
## Create sample data
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
##

# split by month, and apply the last() function to each group
lapply(split(x, "months"), last, "1 week")
```

If you want the results to be a single object, you can `rbind` the list using `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, "months"), last, "1 week"))
               Open     High      Low    Close
2007-01-29 49.85624 49.93038 49.76308 49.91875
2007-01-30 49.85477 50.02180 49.77242 50.02180
2007-01-31 50.07049 50.22578 50.07049 50.22578
2007-02-26 50.88168 50.88168 50.75481 50.75481
2007-02-27 50.74333 50.78909 50.61874 50.69206
2007-02-28 50.69435 50.77091 50.59881 50.77091
2007-03-26 48.34210 48.44637 48.28969 48.28969
2007-03-27 48.25248 48.41572 48.23648 48.30851
2007-03-28 48.33090 48.53595 48.33090 48.53595
2007-03-29 48.59236 48.69988 48.57432 48.69988
2007-03-30 48.74562 49.00218 48.74562 48.93546
2007-03-31 48.95616 49.09728 48.95616 48.97490
2007-04-30 49.13825 49.33974 49.11500 49.33974
2007-05-28 47.90142 47.93398 47.64718 47.64718
2007-05-29 47.65665 47.89342 47.65446 47.87252
2007-05-30 47.78866 47.93267 47.78866 47.83291
2007-05-31 47.82845 47.84044 47.73780 47.73780
2007-06-25 47.20471 47.42772 47.13405 47.42772
2007-06-26 47.44300 47.61611 47.44300 47.61611
2007-06-27 47.62323 47.71673 47.60015 47.62769
2007-06-28 47.67604 47.70460 47.57241 47.60716
2007-06-29 47.63629 47.77563 47.61733 47.66471
2007-06-30 47.67468 47.94127 47.67468 47.76719
```

Note: if it's important, you can wrap `as.zoo()` around it, but `xts` objects are `zoo` objects, so it's probably not necessary.

Comment: Thank you GSee. I tried your fix but it didn't work for me. I only get the last week of the entire year. I added code in my original entry to make it reproducible.

Comment: @user3584057 You need to convert to an `xts` first.  `x <- as.xts(zoodata)`

Comment: Got it. This came out clean: do.call(rbind, lapply(split(as.xts(zoodata), "months"), last, "1 week")) -- Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lapply(split(as.xts(zoodata), "months"), FUN = function(x) last(x,"1 week"))
```

This will give last 1 week of every month. (But the data will end at End of Month date as the last day of the month can end on any day of the week)

Comment: Exact solution I was looking for; worked wonderfully. Thank you!

Comment: Same as mine, but more keystrokes.